# 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903D9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 0, v2580

Tags: windows, entra-id, read-only, rodc

Trying to fastbind against an RODC and I'm getting the following error:

> 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903D9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 0, v2580

I have googled around and don't have any ideas why I'm getting this... I would really appreciate any advice or (even better) then answer to why I'm getting this exception when fastbinding :)

Thanks,

Martin

Comment: So I'm trying to verify log in details by doing a fastbind against a 3rd party readonly domain controller sending the SAMAccountName and Password, but I get the above error back from the RODC. Is that enough information?

Comment: The error message 80090308 means "The token supplied to the function is invalid".  Did you check if there're any compatible issues since you are using a 3rd party RODC?

Comment: Yes third party, but just a Windows 2012 R2 RODC for Active Directory :( Any ideas?

Comment: Did you mean that you are doing a fastbind against the WinServer 2012R2 RODC server? If so, what account you use to doing the fastbind? Also have you checked that if the communication between the RODC and the primary DC used for identity authentication is fine?